# Screen - inherit current window's environment

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen, environment-variables

In GNU Screen, how can I create a new window whose shell inherits the environment of the shell in the current window?

The usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: screen windows don't have environments. Only commands receive an environment when they are executed.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: edited post to reflect this

Answer (score 5):

If you've set environment variables on one screen (say running bash), and then open a new screen, it is a separate bash process and therefore will not pick up the environment on the separate already running bash shell. A quick fix to get around the issue would be:

```
env TERMCAP= env | sed -r 's/^(\w+)=(.*)$/\1="\2"/' > env.sh
```

then once you've <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to get a new shell you can then

```
source env.sh
```

It's hacky and I use `env TERMCAP= env` because the TERMCAP environment variable is multi-line and makes the `sed` far more complicated. It's not pretty, but it works :)

You may want to change it to do:

```
env TERMCAP= env | sed -r 's/^(\w+)=(.*)$/export \1="\2"/' > env.sh
```

So the variables are also exported.

Comment: Yeah this was the only way I could conceive of doing it too. I think you could potentially do a `bash --rcfile env.sh` too.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I voted for it but won't mark it as the answer because I was looking for something less hacky.

Comment: @DravSloan, this doesn't work if there are functions in your environment: you end up getting stuff like `fn="() {function body"` in your env.sh. Also doesn't work if you have a variable with the character " in the value.

Comment: `env` should only report environment variable settings, `set` would report functions, and the sed was set to look for a word `\w+` tied to the beginning of the line `^` followed by a `=`, so it shouldn't of effected functions. But I understand it was very much a "quick hack", I'm not sure if you'll find a solution though :(

Comment: @DravSloan sure, thanks anyway. Regarding the functions in the environment, this is because I exported them ( you can check the behavior with `test() { echo test; } ; export -f test ; env | grep test`). BTW, please tag me if you reply here, otherwise I am not alerted (your post)

Answer (score 0):

Exported variables, as shown by `env` should automatically be inherited by your new `screen`.

However, local variables which you have defined in your shell before starting `screen`, but which you have not exported, will not exist in the screen session.

Depending on how you name your variables, you could use something like this in Bash to get a readable list :

```
(set -o posix ; set) | egrep -v '^(_.*|[A-Z0-9_]+)='
```

`set` by itself would also list tons of functions.

`(set -o posix ; set)` will list only variables, but there is a ton of system variables in that list.

`egrep -v '^(_.*|[A-Z0-9_]+)='` filters out all variables with a name that starts with an underscore, and all those which have only uppercase letters, numbers and underscores. That should get rid of most system variables.

So the list is restricted to variables which also (or only) use lowercase letters (and underscores and numbers). Now you could copy what you want from that list before starting screen, and paste it in there.

Of course, that is only useful if you have many variables which you forgot to export, but you do remember to check them out before starting screen...